# How to change Big Query's google analytics scheme so it includes utm values?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We've set up google analytics a few months ago, and now we want to start marking campaigns by utm's. I do not see utm values in the "events_" table scheme (traffic_source only got source, medium, and name, not campaign or content). I cannot add traffic_source.campaign to the current scheme (and even if I could, it wouldn't change future tables).

How do I configure GA/BQ so it collects this data?

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of parameters missing in GA4 BigQuery Schema and will be added in future releases. So only solution for now is to wait.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? One thing I could think of is intercepting app opens due to deeplinks, manually extracting utm_* parameters, and pushing these as an event to Firebase. Have you tried that?